# Update one column for all rows

Tags: mysql, sql

The value of column `file_path` is something like

```
~/uploaded/de-DE/56/57d8c7d9-dcfc-4208-9f4c-2bf369690bd5.jpeg
```

I am newbie on MySql and I can't update these values for all rows to something like

```
~/uploaded/de-DE/56/
```

This is the Directory only (not the file). I want to remove the name of the file from the string.

Comment: What query are you currently using? If you want to update every row simply remove the where clause. Or, is the problem related to stripping off the filename. Your question doesn't make much sense as it stands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the file name is on all rows, then something like this?

```
UPDATE table SET file_path = SUBSTR(file_path, 1, LENGTH(file_path) - LOCATE('/', REVERSE(file_path))+1) WHERE 1;
```

It's not pretty, but it should work.

It would be simpler if MySQL had a find last occurance, but it doesn't as far as I know; hence the LENGTH - LOCATE REVERSE incantation.

(Back up your table first :)

Comment: Yes, the WHERE is not required. (Unless "SQL_SAFE_UPDATES" flag is in effect)

Answer (score 0):

if you have something like this

`~/uploaded/de-DE/'.$folder.'`

change it to

`~/uploaded/de-DE/'.$folder.'/`

I think you missed a backslash

```
mysql_query("update ".$table." set ".your cell."='".your data."' ");
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I have already changed the query but I have to change the column for the exisiting rows. I HAVE TO remove the file name from the end of the string.